# knockoutjs 3.2.0 Unable to find my "click" binding function in the viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js

My Top-Most ViewModel:

```
function Profile() {
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(0);
    this.name = ko.observable("");
    this.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.newTaskName = ko.observable('');
    this.newTaskDescription = ko.observable('');

    this.addNewTask = function() {
        if (self.newTaskName().trim() != '' && self.newTaskDescription().trim() != '') {
            var newTask = new TaskList();
            var newTaskId = 0;

            $.ajax({
                url: AddTaskUrl + "?userId=" + self.id() + "&taskName=" + self.newTaskName() + "&taskDesc=" + self.newTaskDescription(),
                type: "PUT",
                success: function(data) {
                    newTaskId = data;
                    newTask.taskId(newTaskId);
                    newTask.taskName(self.newTaskName());
                    newTask.taskDescription(self.newTaskDescription());
                    self.tasks.push(newTask);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Instance of this viewmodel applied to `ko.applyBindings()`

This relies on another viewModel for tasks called: TaskList viewModel.

```
function TaskList() {
    var self = this;
    self.taskId = ko.observable(0);
    self.taskName = ko.observable('');
    self.taskDescription = ko.observable('');
    self.removeTask = function() {
        myProfile.tasks.remove(self);
        $.ajax({
            url: RemoveTaskUrl + "?taskId=" + self.taskId(),
            type: "DELETE",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

TaskList viewmodel is bound to UI using a `foreach` binding like so:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span data-bind="text: taskName"></span>
                <br /> <ins data-bind="text: taskDescription"></ins>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: removeTask"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">&nbsp;</i>Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But something isn't working right, because Knockout cannot find `removeTask` function in `TaskList` viewmodel run in a **knockout's** `foreach` binding.

The error message is:

`ReferenceError: removeTask is not defined`

Comment: Is there any other code which add items to the `tasks` array beside your `addNewTask`  method?

Comment: @nemesv there is one part of code that assigns the data received from the server to the `tasks` array. This happens on `$(document).ready()`

Comment: In that code in the `$(document).ready()` do you also use the correct `TaskList` constructor?